# before RVM, what did people do to isolote gems per website on a server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

if you have a server with many rails applications hosted on it, and each have different versions of gems etc., how would you isolate gems per website w/o using RVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpack them into the vendor directory if you're working with Rails.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3 implemented bundler to provide support for this age old problem. Vendoring was the standard, but bundler allows system level installs of several versions of the same gem and will graph the dependency properly for each app at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Specify them in environment.rb with the version number then run rake gems: install